# How to plot 2 files data separately in Gnuplot ?I have one file as "sin.txt" and other as "cos.txt" and i want to plot them separately on one graph

Tags: c++, linux, windows, pipe, gnuplot

```
int main()
{
        FILE *gnuplotPipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
if (gnuplotPipe) {
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "reset \n");
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "plot  'sin.txt' with lines  linestyle 1 lw 5 lc 2  \n");
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "replot  'cos.txt' with lines  linestyle 2 lw 5 lc 2  \n");
        fflush(gnuplotPipe);
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "exit \n");
        pclose(gnuplotPipe);
              }
 return 0;
}
```

// the problem is it is mixing both files data and then making plot.I want both plots to be seperate

Comment: I'm having a hard time working out what you mean by *"separately on one graph"* because *"separately"* implies *"on a different graph"*. Maybe you could click `edit` and add an example or a sketch of what the result should be like? Thank you.

Comment: Is this really a C++ question? Do you know how to do it when you use gnuplot by hand?

Comment: by separately i mean both data should not be mixed .I mean  file "cos.txt" has its own data.It should make its own graph."sin.txt" has its own data it should plot its own graph.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i have tried it .But it only plot "cos.txt" and "sin.txt" appear just for 1 sec .Both plots are not displayed together

Comment: Try to work out how to do it in the shell by reading this... https://alvinalexander.com/technology/gnuplot-charts-graphs-examples/ then adapt to C++.

Comment: Yes its done Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "-persist" option should be written "--persist", or "-p".